# WPF Page Title Bar Hide

Tags: c#, wpf

I know how to hide the title bar in windows: WindowStyle="none". But how can i achieve that with Pages?
I have a code like this:

```
<Page x:Class="SomeNamePage1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
      xmlns:local="SomeName"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="700" WindowHeight="700" WindowWidth="700"
      Title="Page1" Background="#FFFFFF">
```

How can i hide the title bar with the same results as WindowStyle="None"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that's not possible. I solved using a Window as holder for the navigation menu and a frame that switches between Pages for the content.
Hope this helps others!